# Найти те слова, которые содержат максимальное количество неповторяющихся букв

Tags: java

> Пусть имеем текстовый файл на который НЕ накладываются ограничения по его размеру. Мы также не накладываем ограничения на длину строки в этом файле.
>   Текст состоит из слов, например, идентификатор английского языка. Слова граничат между собой промежутками, скобками, кодами операций, вообще символами, что естественно отделяют слова друг от друга. Мы также не будем заниматься вопросами правописания таких слов. Пусть на длина слова мы установим ограничение - 30 букв.
>
> В поле результата нужно вывести слова без повторений, что удовлетворяют определенному условию.
>   На файл, требования к которого сформулированы выше, выполнить следующее:
>   Найти те слова, которые содержат максимальное количество неповторяющихся букв, то есть, буквы которые повторяются в слове не учитывать.

Comment: И где у вас возникли затруднения? Код к вопросу можете добавить кнопкой [правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/718563/edit).

Comment: Не могу понять как мне построить алгоритм и по какому пути пойти

Comment: @МаксимПерепелица: А какие варианты у вас? Попробуйте по любому из путей.

Answer (score -1):

Если будете использовать BufferedReader  советую считывать не строку через readLine, а посимвольно через read, т.к. в файле может быть одна строка и перевода на новую может не быть